# Изменить иконку маркера в MultiRoute

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

подскажите, как можно изменить начальную иконку маркера в MultiRoute, пример 
`var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: []
    }, {
        editorMidPointsType: "via",
        editorDrawOver: false,
        boundsAutoApply: true,
    });`

https://jsfiddle.net/njt7mc60/3/, в начале появляется маркер с буквой "А", вот хотелось бы изменить на свою иконку, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить опции маршрута:

```
wayPointStartIconLayout: "default#image",
wayPointStartIconImageHref: "https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/multiroute_view_options/images/sokolniki.png",
wayPointStartIconImageSize: [30, 30],
wayPointStartIconImageOffset: [-15, -15]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mp2xz57u/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а возможно ли сделать так, чтобы сразу появлялась заданная иконка, а не по нажатию? Как в моем примере, где сразу маркер с буквой "А" высвечивается.

Comment: Нет, нельзя( Этот курсор появляется только для стандартных меток маршрута.